# Return a scalar query result into a batch file variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file

I would like to perform a scalar database query and return the result into a variable in a batch file.

How would one do this? The closest I example in our system that I see is if I return an exit code based on a scalar query result.

```
    Z:\SQL2005\90\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd -S servername -dCLASS -E -Q "EXIT(select case run_type when 'Q' then 200 else 100 end from cycle_date where cycle = '1')">NUL
    if %errorlevel% == 200 call %SQLSERVER%
QRTLY.BAT               
    if %errorlevel% == 100 call %SQLSERVER%
MTHLY.BAT
```

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Here's some sqlcmd help info:

```
-v var = value[ var=value...] 
Creates a sqlcmdscripting variable that can be used in a sqlcmd script. Enclose the value in quotation marks if the value contains spaces. You can specify multiple var="values" values. If there are errors in any of the values specified, sqlcmd generates an error message and then exits.

sqlcmd -v MyVar1=something MyVar2="some thing" 

sqlcmd -v MyVar1=something -v MyVar2="some thing" 

-x disable variable substitution 
Causes sqlcmd to ignore scripting variables. This is useful when a script contains many INSERT statements that may contain strings that have the same format as regular variables, such as $(variable_name).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this in a batch file. It returns the LogicalFilename for a SQL Server Database data file. This only works if there is one data file in the DB.

So the result is the environment variable DATABASEFILENAME is set to say AdventureWorks_Data.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i IN (`sqlcmd -w200 -h-1 -E -Q"set nocount on; Select df.name  From sysdatabases as d Inner Join sysaltfiles as df on d.dbid=df.dbid Where d.name ='$(DatabaseName)' and df.Fileid =1"`) DO set DATABASEFILENAME=%%i
```

Comment: Your answer looks good. Just one follow up question: I'd liek to full qualify the path to sqlcmd, eg, SET sqlcmd="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe", but when I do so, I get "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: Here's the modified line: FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i IN (`%sqlcmd% -S %server% -d %db% -w200 -h-1 -E -Q "set nocount on; select REPORTING_DATE FROM dbo.CURRENT_REPORTING_DATE"`) DO set REPORTING_DATE=%%i

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860897/issue-executing-an-exe-when-the-path-has-spaces

Comment: The problem is more than likely the spaces in the path in your batch file. The path to SQLCMD is usually in the path so you shouldn't need to set the full path to it. Check if your folder is listed in a CMD window echo %path%

Answer (score 4):

How about saving it to a file without headers then reading the contents back in?

```
sqlcmd -S(local)\SQLExpress -dMyDatabase -Umyuser -Pmypassword -W -h -1 -Q  "SELECT Top 1 MyValue FROM MyTable" -o sqlcmdoutput.txt 
set /p x= <sqlcmdoutput.txt
del sqlcmdoutput.txt
echo My scalar value is %x%
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28SQL.90%29.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773%28SQL.90%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yeah, but I need help with the syntax.