# Issue executing an exe when the path has spaces.

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

This works:

```
SET server=MyServer
SET db=MyDb 

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i IN (`sqlcmd -S %server% -d %db% -w200 -h-1 -E -Q "set nocount on; select REPORTING_DATE FROM dbo.CURRENT_REPORTING_DATE"`) DO set REPORTING_DATE=%%i 
ECHO The Reporting Date is %REPORTING_DATE%
```

But when I try to fully qualify the path to sqlcmd...

```
SET sqlcmdexe="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" SET server=MyServer SET db=MyDb 

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%i IN (` %sqlcmdexe% -S %server% -d %db%
-w200 -h-1 -E -Q "set nocount on; select REPORTING_DATE FROM dbo.CURRENT_REPORTING_DATE"`) DO set REPORTING_DATE=%%i  ECHO The Reporting Date is %REPORTING_DATE%
```

I get the error:

The system cannot find the path specified.

...presumably because of the spaces in the folder name.

How do I change the path to a tilde path (w/o spaces) or better yet, quote it so that this statement executes properly?

Note that there is a backwards tic before %sqlcmdexe% , not sure why I don't see it, at least in IE6. Yes, 6!

Comment: You could use `call %sqlcmdexe%`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch File: FOR /F doesn't work if path has spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474738/batch-file-for-f-doesnt-work-if-path-has-spaces)

Comment: Yes your call-trick there inspired me to examine the underlying problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How do I change the path to a tilde path (w/o spaces)*

As I don't have sqlcmd.exe installed, I use a different example. See for example this:

```
@echo off
set sqlcmdexe=C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Connection Wizard\icwconn2.exe
echo %sqlcmdexe%

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("%sqlcmdexe%") do set sqlcmdexe=%%~sa
echo %sqlcmdexe%
```

Run on my system, the output is:

```
C:\temp>envtest
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Connection Wizard\icwconn2.exe
C:\PROGRA~1\INTERN~1\CONNEC~1\icwconn2.exe
```

But I don't know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the quotes to work with Strings... but You have never use spaces next to equal sign:

```
set "sqlcmdexe=c:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\Connection Wizard\icwconn2.exe"
echo.%sqlcmdexe%
```

Hope it helps =)